# Manually installing steam on Debian 10

Tags: debian, deb, steam

After downloading the .DEB package from the steam website and extracting the files, I get a pop up when clicking the launcher that says "The desktop file steam.desktop is in an insecure location and not marked as executable". Is it still safe to click launch and if not, what should I do?

Comment: Any terminal -> `chmod +x ~/Desktop/*desktop`

Answer (score 0):

- Any terminal application -> `chmod +x ~/Desktop/*desktop`

or

- Right click the desktop file -> Allow to run or something.